# Problem editing cell in office script (typescript)

Tags: typescript, office-js, office-scripts

everyone.

I need code that monitors active or selected cells to block them when a user is no longer in them. I know an eventual problem with this will be when the user selects the cell and still doesn't make any changes, but it's something I'll have to deal with since we don't support something like 'onChange' yet. The problem is that if the user starts editing, the getActiveCell/getSelectedRange method fails and stops the script, even though I call it inside a try block. The code below shows the heart of the idea, when the code manages to know which cell the user is in and when he leaves that cell. The next step would be to use setLock in place of console.log and everything would be fine.

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook)
{
  while(true){
    try{
      let cell = workbook.getSelectedRange().getAddress();
    }
    catch(e){}
    console.log(cell)
    while(workbook.getSelectedRange().getAddress() == cell){}
  }
}
```

Comment: There aren't Worksheet Change events in Office Scripts

Comment: Events aren't currently supported in office scripts. It looks like you're trying to run this script as a proxy for events but it won't work. If you want to use events you'd need to use either VBA or Office.js.

Comment: @beyphy But do you know anything about the error even in the try block? If the error were caught and ignored, it would be a big step forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to lock a cell once the user has finished editing in it and moved away, you could probably try something like below:

```js
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
  let lastSelectedCell = "";
  let cell = "";
  let errorCaughtBefore = false;
  let worksheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
  if (!worksheet.getProtection().getProtected()) {
    worksheet.getProtection().protect();
  }
  while (true) {
    try {
      cell = workbook.getSelectedRange().getAddress();
      if (errorCaughtBefore && lastSelectedCell) {
        console.log(lastSelectedCell);
        worksheet.getProtection().unprotect();
        worksheet.getRange(lastSelectedCell).getFormat().getProtection().setLocked(true);
        worksheet.getProtection().protect();
        errorCaughtBefore = false;
      }
    }
    catch (e) {
      errorCaughtBefore = true;
      lastSelectedCell = cell;
    }
  }
}
```

**Please note**:

- Without proper eventing support, all this workaround is pretty hacky and might be unreliable.
- Also, according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/scripts/develop/web-client-performance#avoid-using-trycatch-blocks-in-or-surrounding-loops, invoking `try/catch` inside of a loop could lead to slow performance of the script.